# Additional parameters for TextBoxFor() in ASP.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I was using a textbox to do the following:

`<input style="width:50px;" type="text" id="blah" value="@model.value1" @if(model.id!=1){ <text>disabled</text>}/>`

This basically shows a textbox which is disabled under specific circumstances.
I decided to replace this with a more "mvc-friendly" way.

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.value1, new { id = "blah" })`

But not sure how to add in the disabled attribute (Dynamically) I can get it to do it statically easilly by adding a `disabled=true`value into the `new{}`.

I did try using this:

  `@if (<condition>) { var disable = true;  }
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.value1, new { id = "blah", disabled = disable })`

But this also didn't work. Am i taking the right approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@{
    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "id", "blah" }
    };
    if (<condition>) 
    { 
        attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
    }
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.value1, attributes)
```

Obviously that's ugly as hell and you should never even be thinking of polluting your view like that. I would simply write a custom reusable HTML helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex,
        object htmlAttributes,
        bool disabled
    )
    {
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        if (disabled)
        {
            attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
        }

        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(ex, attributes);
    }
}
```

that you could use in the view as simply as:

```
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(m => model.value1, new { id = "blah" }, <condition>)
```

Comment: Thanks, still getting used to custom HtmlHelpers. Really useful info!

Answer (score 2):

You have a scope issue with the above disable doesn't exist outside the scope of the if statement,

my recommendation is this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.value1, new { id = "blah", disabled = (<condition>) })
```

EDIT:

You can use

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.value1, new { id = "blah", disabled = (<condition>) ? "disabled" : "" })
```

If you want to insert the word disabled rather than a bool, from memory this is kinda a browser specific setting some are happy with "true" others with "disabled"

Comment: This validates fine, but I think as im using the word "disabled" it automatically disables the box.

Comment: See my edit, you can use a ternary operator in-line to give different values based on an if statement.

Comment: disabled keyword automatically disables inputs